# Reference annotation on bundle field

Tags: java, multithreading, osgi, declarative-services

I'm developing an application with OSGi. Looking inside the [OSGi compendium 6.0 (section 112.8.1)](https://osgi.org/download/r6/osgi.cmpn-6.0.0.pdf)  I've come across the declarative service; in particular I looked the following paragraph:

> For a field, the defaults for the Reference annotation are:
>
> - The name
>     of the bind method or field is used for the name of the reference.
> - 1:1 cardinality if the field is not a collection. 0..n cardinality if    the field is a collection.
> - Static reluctant policy if the field is not declared volatile. Dynamic reluctant policy if the field is declared volatile
> - The requested service is the type of the field.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> @Reference
> volatile Collection<LogService> log;
> ```

Now, I read from [Neil Bartlett's OSGi in practice (section 11.10.2)](http://njbartlett.name/files/osgibook_preview_20091217.pdf) that synchronization and concurrency of *bind* and *unbind* methods of `Reference annotation` are a bit tricky (especially in dynamic policy scnearios). In particular, a thread-safe example of a reference of a service via annotation may be:

```
@Component( provide = MailboxListener.class, properties = { "service.ranking = 10"})
public class LogMailboxListener implements MailboxListener {
    private final AtomicReference<Log> logRef = newAtomicReference <Log> () ;

    public void messagesArrived ( String mboxName, Mailbox mbox, long [ ] ids ) {
        Log log = logRef.get();
        if (log != null ) 
            log.log(Log.INFO, ids.length + "message(s) arrived in mailbox " + mboxName, null);
        else
            System.err.println("No log available!");
    }

    @Reference( service = Log.class, dynamic = true, optional = true )
    public void setLog(Log log) {
        logRef.set(log);
    }

    public void unsetLog(Log log) {
        logRef.compareAndSet(log, null);
    }
}
```

I think I grasped from the book why there the dynamic policy needs this adjustements from the multi-threading scenario. My question is: **if the reference annotation were on a field (declarative service 1.3) how could I achieve thread-safety? Only by defining the reference as "volatile" (as compendium suggest)? Or there is some tricky part that will create problems in the application?**

Thanks for any kind reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a dynamic policy reference on a field, the field must be volatile. In your example, each time the set of LogServices change, a new collection is injected into the field. So this will be safe since if your code is iterating over the old collection, the old collection is unaltered. When you code goes back to the log field, it will see the new collection.

So all you need to do is declare the field volatile and do not store the field value somewhere else since the field will be updated to a new collection whenever the set of bound services changes.

Comment: So, in order to use field-annotated bundle reference I need to, whenever I need to use the reference itself, use the field itself (and not a local copy like `LogService a = this.log`)? Let me provide an example (for semplicity I will use a simple `LogService` instead of a collection of them): `public void foo() { if (this.log != null) { this.log.log("foo started"); //do other code }` Is this thread-safe with `log` field just set to volatile? Or do I need further operations?

Comment: When ever you need to use the logservice, copy it into a local var from the field, use the local var and then let the local var go out of scope. My point was not to copy it from the field into some other location which is held for a long time (such as another object).

Comment: @BJHargave Ah ok, now I understand! I've read the exact same procedure you just wrote in Neil's OSGi in practice, but from your comment I mistakenly thought you suggested avoiding the use of the local variable. Now all is perfectly clear! I feared writing thread-safe service references was different by using annotated-field, but apparently is all much more easy! I don't even need AtomicReference or checks on `null` inside the unbind method. It appears modern OSGi references should use as much as possible field-annotated version of DS rather than the bind/unbind method, right?

Comment: To the extent that your component implementation does not need notification of changes in the bound services (as you would get with calls to bind and unbind methods), then yes, using field references is much simpler and less error prone to use.